# How to Prepare HP QTP/UFT scripts for Dynamic Fields?

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

Required Help here to prepare HP UFT Test Scripts for Dynamically changing Input Fields on Selection.

**Scenario:**

i have 2 types of list items and it will display various fields based on selection.
1.14 digit card - perform customer registration(different fields)
2.16 Digit Card - Perform Customer Registration(different fields)

Can i use if condition or any other conditions to Prepare Keyword driven framework to prepare test scripts for above type of scenarios.

Suppose for Login with 14 digit cards.

```
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").List(html id:=cardtypes).Select "#1"
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("html id:=userNameId").Set khuname
Browser("name:=Login Screen").Page("title:=Login Screen").WebEdit("html id:=passwordId").Set khpasswd
Browser().Page().WebButton().Click
```

After Click on Login then in Customer Registration only selected card type fields will display,Like this i want to write the code for entire application
modules,please help me how can i prepare test scripts for this type of application.

Comment: Yes.  Firstly you'd need some quotes around your `html id:=cardtypes` though. As for the selection of one card type or the other, surely you can simply check the length of the card number, and select the appropriate card type based on that, then interact with whatever set of fields appears?

Answer (score 0):

At this point without knowing the Fields type it's a bit hard to say.
It depends on Object Property Or Their Position

Let say there are 10 fields for 14 digit Card Type  and 15 fields for 16 digit card type.
and among them 5-6 are common then you can perform operation on them in Common place in your function.
if there are some parts of changing in your Fields object property(like in name or htmlid etc then you can store then in OR making their property Regular expression Enabled. )

As i've said, it depends on the property of your field objects And also on Other Factors.

Noe if they are different also, you can create a function which entertains an array/Dictionary (This either at runtime You can provide The Array/Dictionary values or you can configure them to be read from either xml,txt,excel file and store those in an Array/Dictionary.)

Keep first element of array/ or first key-value pair Dictionary to specify the card type & the rest for field values. And based upon that you can make decision & create your function.

Your function should look like following.for example using Array

public function CardRegister(*****Pass Array/Dictionary Object****)
{
'   Let say array object is objArr

If (objArr(0)="14 Digit card") then

.       Select Desired entry from Weblist

'       Perform 14 digit card registration here

Elseif (objArr(0)="16 Digit card") then

.       Select Desired entry from Weblist

'       Perform 16 digit card registration here

End If

' If common fields are there then you canperform operation on then in Common are.

'*************** common Fields**********

'----- Do something

'************* common Fields ***********

'  Click on Register button & then Validaet whether it's successful

}

Now you can Mention this CardRegister function as Keyword & either user

1)Eval

or

2) Execute

to call your function as Keyword. (This Keyword can also be put in xml/txt/excel file & u can configure you way of calling the Function)

This way you can implement. I hope you have got an idea. Let me know if you have concerns.